# Integer valued polynomial implies integer coefficients

Tags: calculus, polynomials

22. Let $f(x) = Ax^2 + Bx + C$ where $A, B, C$ are real numbers. If
    $f(x)$ is an integer whenever $x$ is an integer, then

(a) $2 A$ and $A + B$ are integers, but $C$ is not an integer.

(b) $A + B$ and $C$ are integers, but $2 A$ is not an integer.

(c) $2 A$, $A + B$ and $C$ are all integers.

(d) None of these.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020).

Comment: **HINT:** Use the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 3):

As gt6989b notes, $f(0) = C$, and since $f(x)$ is an integer for any integer $x$, $C$ must be an integer as well.

Also, we have $f(1) = A + B + C$. This is equal to $B+A = f(1) - C$. However, note that $f(1)$ must be an integer, and we have already shown that $C$ is an integer. The difference of two integers is also an integer, thus $A+B$ is an integer as well.

We also have $f(2) = 4A + 2B + C$. Since $A+B$ is an integer, $2A+2B$ is an integer as well, and since $C$ is an integer, $2A+2B+C$ is also an integer. If we subtract this from $f(2)$, we get $f(2) - (2A+2B+C) = 2A$. Since $f(2)$ and $2A+2B+C$ are integers, their difference must also be an integer, thus $2A$ is an integer as well. So, we have $2A$, $A+B$, and $C$ as integers, thus the answer is C.

Comment: Or $2A= f(1)+f(-1)-2C\in\Bbb Z$ if $C\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: I strongly prefer for the OP to exhibit at least *some* effort on his problem

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Note $f(0)=C$, so $C$ is an integer, which would eliminate (a). What can you imply from $f(1)$ and $f(-1)$? Can you finish?